# Duplicate PDF file created when button is clicked the 2nd time.

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, pdf, adobe

I followed this [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020001758/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/030911-1.aspx) here on how to create html table to pdf in asp.net

I followed the sample code and wired it to my button event handler, and when i clicked it, the pdf file is automatically generated in the respective file directory. But when i clicked it for the second time, it says my filename pdf has been used. I checked the file directory and there is indeed a pdf file being generated. How do i stop the duplication of pdf files when i clicked the button the 2nd time. I'm trying to convert my html table data into a pdf format. I'm wondering if i'm following the correct source.

Attempted sample code :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
        var output = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("MyFirstTestPDF.pdf"), FileMode.Create);
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
        document.Open();
        var welcomeParagraph = new Paragraph("Hello, World!");
        document.Add(welcomeParagraph);
document.Close();
    }
```

My html table in asp.net

```
<ul id="Report">
 Case ID :
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCase" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLCase_SelectedIndexChanged"
AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
<asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select Member Report ID</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<table style="width: 100%; height: 576px;">
<tr>
<th style="width: 98px; height: 49px;">Full Name :</th>
<td style="width: 351px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
<th style="height: 49px; width: 76px">Contact :</th>
<td style="width: 185px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblContact" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="width: 98px">Location :</th>
<td style="width: 351px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
<th style="width: 76px">Type of Crime :</th>
<td style="width: 185px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblTOC" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="width: 98px">Picture : </th>
<td style="width: 351px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblPicture" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
<th style="width: 76px">Citizen Report Date &amp; Time :</th>
<td style="width: 185px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblCRDT" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="width: 98px">AssignTo :</th>
<td style="width: 351px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblAssign" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
<th style="width: 76px">Police Report Date &amp; Time :</th>
<td style="width: 185px; height: 49px; text-align: left;">
  <asp:Label ID="lblPRDT" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="width: 98px; height: 100px;">Citizen Report :</th>
<td colspan="4" style="height: 100px" text-align:"left">
  <asp:Label ID="lblCR" runat="server" Text="" style="display: block; text-align:  left;"></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th style="width: 98px; height: 135px;">Police&nbsp; Report :</th>
<td colspan="4" style="height: 135px" text-align: "left">
  <asp:Label ID="lblPR" runat="server" Text="" style="display: block; text-align: left;"></asp:Label>
</td>
</tr>

    <tr>
<th style="width: 98px; height: 135px;">Official&nbsp; Report :</th>
<td colspan="4" style="height: 135px" text-align: "left">
  <asp:Label ID="lblOR" runat="server" Text="" style="display: block; text-align: left;"></asp:Label>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you close the document?

```
// Close the Document - this saves the document contents to the output stream
document.Close();
```

Comment: you're right. however i got another problem with duplicated pdf files.

Comment: that's because all your files will have the same file name =>  var output = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("MyFirstTestPDF.pdf"), FileMode.Create);

Comment: How do i make a dynamic title name? I have seen some website able to create duplicated pdf file with auto-increment to a number in the pdf file name.

Comment: To auto-increment you will have to maintain a count somewhere in a database. I would suggest use a timestamp. Try this: var filename = "MyTestPDF" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".pdf";         var output = new FileStream(Server.MapPath(filename), FileMode.Create);